# Adding conditional text on the destroy popup using Kendo and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I'm trying to display conditional text on the popup when clicking `Delete` on a record from a Kendo grid. Is this possible?

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.contactInfos)
 .Name("HOAddrListGrid")
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
         .Model(model =>
         {
             model.Id(o => o.contactID);
         })
     .Read(read => read.Action("HOAddrList_Read", "Homeowner_v2"))
     .Create(update => update.Action("HOAddrList_Insert", "Homeowner_v2", new { uid = ViewData["UserID"] }))
     .Update(update => update.Action("HOAddrList_Update", "Homeowner_v2", new { uid = ViewData["UserID"] }))
     .Destroy(update => update.Action("HOAddrList_Destroy", "Homeowner_v2", new { uid = ViewData["UserID"] }))
     .Events(events =>
     {
         events.Error("error");
         events.RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd_ContactGrid");
     })
 )
 .ToolBar(toolbar =>
 {
     toolbar.Create().Text("New Contact").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "display: none;" });
 })
.Columns(columns =>
{
 columns.Bound(o => o.contactID).Hidden(true);
 columns.Bound(o => o.hoID).Hidden(true);
 columns.Bound(o => o.label).Width(180);
 columns.Bound(o => o.descr).Title("Contact");
 columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
}).Width(172);

})
.Sortable()
.Selectable()
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("HOContactEdit").Window(w => w.Title("Edit Contact"));
))
```

I understand you can add custom text to the Destroy button, but any change I can add a conditional here?

```cs
command.Edit(); command.Destroy(// some conditional text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DisplayDeleteConfirmation` option to customize the default message:

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you really really sure you want to do this?"))
```

To conditionally display the message you can add an if clause:

```
.Editable(editable => {
    editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp);
    if(true) //check condition
    {
        editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you really really sure you want to do this?");
    }
})
```